# Why doesn't SSO between my Digital Experience sites work?

Tags: single-sign-on, experience-cloud, saml, digital-experience

The steps here [Configure SAML SSO Between Salesforce Orgs or Experience Cloud Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_between_multiple_orgs.htm&type=5) are detailed and clear. But having gone through those, I'm still seeing the the separate logins rather than the single sign-on for some Digital Experience sites.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "Select login options to display on the login page" section in the Workspace → Administration → Login & Registration → Login Page Setup that once a "SAML Single Sign-On Settings" has been created offers that option as well as the normal username and password one.

So my missing step was to switch over to the single sign-on entry as below:

[image: Login page setup]

Might be mentioned somewhere, but I didn't find it when I Googled and only came across it by accident.

I recommend this video on the subject [Single Sign On (SSO) for a Salesforce Community](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNAdzUvLAa0) by
Samarth Ahuja that includes this step.